# function excuting on load rather than on click

Tags: jquery, function

I have a function that scrolls the page to a particular div. and another function that reloads the page and calls scroll function.

It almost works how I want it to, the issue that I'm struggling with is that the scroll function loads whenever the page is loaded, rather than just on the on click event. I suspect it's something really simple but can't seem to figure it out.

The code I have is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(scrolldown) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#main-content').offset().top - 10
    }, 'slow');
});

$('#return').on("click", function() {
    location.reload();
    scrolldown();
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't be related to the reload? Because that function reloads the current document:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Comment: I think you're confused as to what's going on in the `ready`. That's not declaring a function called `scrolldown`, that's a function taking a parameter called scolldown. Or do you have `scrolldown` declared somewhere else?

Comment: because your function is a closure.... It is not a named function. It is being called when the page is ready...

Comment: Maybe you should put the click function inside document.ready code.?

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not named, you have it as a closure that gets called on document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function scrolldown () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#main-content').offset().top - 10
    }, 'slow');
  }

  $('#return').on("click", function() {
    location.reload();
    scrolldown();  //THIS WILL NEVER RUN
  });

});
```

Now the line I highlighted will never run. The reason is the page refreshes. The code after it will not run. It does NOT magically run on the next page load. So what you are trying to do is impossible. You can not run the code after the click and after the refresh.

What can you do? You can set a cookie/localstorage to say that the page was reloaded and check that when the page is loaded. If the value is set, than scroll the page. Other option, use a querystring... not sure that is the best idea. Or you can not reload the page and use Ajax to do whatever you are trying to accomplish by reloading the page.

Or you can use anchors which is what people normally use to set the location of the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if (localStorage.scroll) {  //if localstroage has the key, than run animation
    localStorage.removeItem("scroll");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#main-content').offset().top - 10
    }, 'slow');
  }

  $('#return').on("click", function() {
    localStorage.scroll = true;  //set the storage so code runs on next page load
    location.reload();
  });

});
```

Comment: thanks for that - that makes my mistakes clearer. I suspect I've gone done the wrong path and need to rethink this some more! thanks again